# Share image on Google Plus without using intent

Tags: android, image, google-plus, sharing, httpconnection

How can I share or upload a image on Google+ without using intents? I do not want to use `ACTION_EVENT`

Comment: Why don't you want to use intents?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's not yet in the Google + API.

Check this doc:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/